# how to allow paging gridview when all rows are generated programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is there a way to allow paging on a grid view when it is already filled programmatically?

Here is my code:

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<Dictionary<Control,int>,int> kvp in ls)
{
     foreach (KeyValuePair<Control, int> kvp2 in kvp.Key)
     {
          GridView1.Rows[kvp.Value].Cells[kvp2.Value].Controls.Add(kvp2.Key);
     }
}
GridView1.AllowPaging = true; // this is what i wanna do
GridView1.PageSize = 4;
```

My gridview isn't filled by datatable, only thanks to this dictionary.

Edit: if I databind the gridview, all the data will be lost, so I can't use this.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: I am targetting c#ASP.NET, I will add tag